# JUnit testing hangs at clientSocket.accept()?

Tags: java, sockets, testing, junit, server

I need to test some client/server application using JUnit and I'm having trouble testing the connection of a client to the server. It seems that the test hangs at the "Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept()" line in the server class, and it's not letting me connect a new client.

Here's the JUnit class:

```
 @Test
        public void testNetServerComm_1() throws Exception {
            server = new NetServerComm();
            assertNotNull(server);
        }

        @Test
        public void testAddMessageToQueue_1() throws Exception {
            NetServerComm fixture = new NetServerComm();
            NetServerSideMessage msg = new NetServerSideMessage(birdsong.comm.ServerSideMessage.Type.BIRDSONG_MESSAGE, "",
                    "");
            fixture.addMessageToQueue(msg);
            assertEquals(1, fixture.getMsgQueueSize());
        }

    @Test
        public void testClientIsConnected_1() throws Exception {
            NetServerComm fixture = new NetServerComm();
            fixture.start();

            //test doesn't go further that this..

            String nickname = "john";
            new NetClientComm().connect("127.0.0.1", nickname);
            boolean result = fixture.isClientConnected(nickname);
            assertTrue(result);
        }
```

Client Class:

```
//connects to the server
@Override
    public void connect(String host, String nickname) {
        try {
            clientNickname = nickname;
            System.out.println("Address= " + host + " and NickName = " + nickname);
            socket = new Socket(host, NetServerComm.PORTO); //8080
            System.out.println("Socket = " + socket);
            serverMsg = new NetServerSideMessage(ServerSideMessage.Type.CLIENT_CONNECTED, null, clientNickname);
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            out.writeObject(serverMsg);
            isConnected = true;
            messageHandler = new Thread(new MessageHandler(socket));
            messageHandler.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed connecting to the server.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Server Class:

```
//starts the server
@Override
    public void start() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORTO); //8080
            System.out.println("Servidor is online: " + serverSocket);
            try {
                while (true) {
                    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

                     //test hangs at the method above^^^

                    checkNewClient(clientSocket);
                    if (nameCheck == true)
                        new Thread(new ClientHandler(clientSocket)).start();
                }
            } finally {
                System.out.println("Closing the server..");
                serverSocket.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you start() method is getting executed by the same Thread as the test, so it blocks there (at the accept() part). Could you try to have this method executed by a new Thread instead ?

Comment: That seems to have done the job :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you start() method is getting executed by the same Thread as the test, so it blocks there (at the accept() part). Could you try to have this method executed by a new Thread instead ? – Berger

That seems to have done the job :) – JDev